# Deezer SDK DZ.player.getCurrentTrack and DZ.player.getTrackList always return null on Android

Tags: javascript, android, deezer

In my Deezer InApp, when I call the Deezer Javascript SDK `DZ.player.getCurrentTrack` or `DZ.player.getTrackList` method, they always return `null` on Android, even though on desktop and iOS I get the current track or tracklist as expected. I am certain that there is a track loaded in the player, and it makes no difference if the player is paused or playing.

EDIT: Also, the `current_track` event doesn't seem to be fired.

Is this is a bug in the Android version of the SDK? Any workaround available?

Comment: The bug is now fixed. You can try again if you want to. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Yes, it works now, even without updating the app or anything, thank you!